# Enum defined as IsOptional cannot be queried for null values

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, ef-fluent-api

I have defined an Enum property on an Entity via Fluent API as IsOptional. The database reflects the IsOptional as it shows it as a nullable type. When I attempt to query this Entity property for null values I get the following error:

```
The 'UserType' property on 'Group' could not be set to a 'null' value. 
You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'UserType'.
```

The query is as follows:

```
var groups = (from g in db.Groups
              let reqs = from r in db.Requests 
              where r.Id == requestId from gg in r.Groups select gg.Id                                  
              where g.ContentArea.Id == db.Requests.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Id == requestId).ContentArea.Id
              where !reqs.Contains(g.Id)
              where (g.UserType == db.Requests.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Id == requestId).User.UserType || g.UserType == (UserType?)null)
              select g).ToList();
```

and the part that specifically breaks is after the OR statement

```
g.UserType == (UserType?)null
```

I've tried to compare g.UserType to null, set an instance of UserType? nullType = null and compared that but nothing seems to work. It seems to be a shortcoming of EF. Any suggestions?

**EDIT:** Included the entire query as requested.

Comment: Please show the full query, I think the problem is in another part of it.

Comment: I think `UserType` is nullable in the database and not in the class.

Comment: @GertArnold you are correct. I defined it as UserType? and it worked. Respond with an answer so I can give you credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not in the structure of the statement, it's in the entities EF tries to materialize. `Group` has a property `UserType` that's not nullable. But in the database it is nullable and some of the returned records have null values for it.

So you either have to make the property nullable:

```
UserType? UserType { get; set; }
```

or make sure that the statement doesn't return null values.